# how to show a menu of buttons in web form on mouse over event

Tags: c#, .net, button, webforms, mouseover

I designed a web form with few buttons on top of it. I need to show a list of sub buttons when user points to each of the buttons. For instance when he/she points to button called media, a list of buttons under media button should open called pic, video and sounds.
I appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Look at some javascript menus in following link,

http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/20-excellent-javascript-navigation-techniques-and-examples/

http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/menu/javascript.htm